# Kibana String URL image template authentication

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to work out whether it is possible to attach authentication, or make kibana send some sort of authentication with URL templates for field formatters in kibana.

Field formatters are found in:

> Management -> Kibana -> Indices -> INDEX_NAME -> Field.

It is possible to display images on URLs with this. For this purpose, I have configured my URL template to be something among the lines of:

> localhost:8080/resolve/{imageId}

The imageId is provided via the `{{value}}` variable and this works all fine.

now, the server running the image resolver has access to data beyond the scope of the image. I would like to add some authentication to the request coming in from Kibana. I have printed available headers and only gotten this:

```
{host=[localhost:8082], connection=[keep-alive], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36], accept=[image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8], referer=[http://localhost:5601/app/kibana], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], accept-language=[en-GB,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6], cookie=[JSESSIONID.1f47f03c=node01x3mhn2jmd7g4qby84ryfcxmd1.node0; screenResolution=1920x1080; JSESSIONID.d86b4be4=node01gzefm5lc0i3c9itul3p0zoil1.node0; JSESSIONID.9211a7ee=node01v32dtus1uphtcvg72es74h681.node0]}
```

I can't find any basic authentication in there that I can take advantage of. I am not sure if the cookies can be used to resolve the authentication in a way?

My question is: Can I send basic authentication of the logged in user as part of my request? If so, how?

I realise this is not too much to go on. I am attaching a screenshot for hopefully a little more clarity.

[image: Kibana edit field]

Answer (score 0):

I asked this on the elastic board as well who informed me of:

> The cookies won't be sent to the third-party because of the same
>   origin restrictions that browsers put in place. Its not possible.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-string-url-image-template-authentication/165786/2

Thanks!